# How to find an asymptotic expansion of integral?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

How to find an asymptotic expansion of integral by using Watson lemma

$$ I(x) =\int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{-xt} {(1+\cos t)}^{1/2}dt$$

as $x \to \infty$?

We know,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}  = \cos x$$

letting $$(1+\cos t)^{1/2} = \sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) = \sqrt{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{-1}{4})^kt^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

And by Watson's Lemma

$$I \sim\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac{a_n\Gamma(\alpha + \beta_n + 1)}{x^{\alpha + \beta_n + 1}}$$

So,
$$\beta_n = 0$$
$$\ a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!} $$

Is it correct answer?
$$ I \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}n!}{(2n)!x^{n+1}}  $$

Comment: Could you give a reference to Watson's lemma (which should be elementary, of course :) ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma

Answer (score 5):

> **Watson's Lemma**
>
> If the integral, $$\int_0^T f(t)e^{-xt}\ dt,\quad (0<T\leq\infty)$$ converges for sufficiently large $x$, where $f(t)$ has the
> asymptotic series given by, $$f(t)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^{\alpha n+\beta},\quad t\to0$$ then the full asymptotic expansion as
> $x\to\infty$ of the integral is given by, $$\int_0^T f(t)e^{-xt}\ dt\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n\Gamma(\alpha n + \beta+1)}{x^{\alpha n + \beta+1}}$$

Applying this to the problem, the Maclaurin series of $f(t)$ is,$$\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt2(-1/4)^n}{\Gamma(2n+1)}t^{2n}$$
so the parameters are,
$$\alpha=2,\quad\beta=0,\quad a_n=\frac{\sqrt2(-1/4)^n}{\Gamma(2n+1)},$$
hence by [Watson's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma),
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{-xt} {(1+\cos t)}^{1/2}\ dt&\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt2(-1/4)^n}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\frac{\Gamma{(2n+1)}}{x^{2n+1}}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{\sqrt2}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(4x^2)^n}}
\end{align*}$$
as $x\to+\infty$, which agrees with @ClaudeLeibovici's asymptotic.

Answer (score 4):

*I am not familiar with Watson lemma but I found the result surprising; then, this too long comment.*
$$\int e^{-xt} {(1+\cos t)}^{1/2}\,dt=\frac{2 e^{-t x} \sqrt{\cos (t)+1} \left(\tan
   \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-2x\right)}{4 x^2+1}\tag1$$
$$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{-xt} {(1+\cos t)}^{1/2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{2} \left(4 x+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} e^{-\frac{\pi  x}{4}} \left(\tan
   \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)-2 x\right)\right)}{4 x^2+1}\tag 2$$ which is asymptotic to $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)\tag 3$$ which is the start of $$\frac{\sqrt 2}x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{(4x^2)^n}$$

Using $x=100$, $(2)$ would give $$I(100)=\frac{\sqrt{2} \left(400-\left(201-\sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} e^{-25 \pi
   }\right)}{40001}\approx  \color{blue}{0.0141417820792}$$ while $(3)$ would give
$$\frac{39999}{2000000 \sqrt{2}}\approx \color{red}{0.01414178207}03$$

Your last formula would lead to $$I(x)\sim \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{12 x^3}-\frac{1}{120
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$